# Front Flip Animation Messed Up Due To Quaternion

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode, quaternion

I made a front flip animation for my character however when I play the animation, the character goes to the keyframes, but once it gets past the second to last keyframe and goes to the final pose, it rotates all the way back around the opposite way.

Now I was told that its due to the bones on the rig being set to quaternion and I needed to set them to euler, however, I have found when I did that it messed up the animation.

What could I do?

https://streamable.com/kphuab

Answer (score 1):

Switch to pose mode and find and select the bone that rotates backwards. Go to the last keyframe in your animation (frame 80 it looks like), and *negate the W, X, Y, Z of the rotation* in the Bone Properties panel, ie. replace 0.1 with -0.1. Insert a keyframe to save the values. Your rotation should now work.

(I think there's an op that will do this automatically but I can't remember what it is...)

Comment: So a little update. I found an addon that would automatically convert the bones to euler rotation instead of Quaternion. So I did that however now the problem occurs in between 48 and 56 keyframes.